# NSMenu renders incorrectly, goes transparent

Tags: xcode, macos, nsmenu

I've a menu bar app that has an intermittent rendering issue. Whenever I open the app from the menu, it work fine, but at times when the app in running and I click on the app icon from the dock / Launchpad, I get this weird layout of the menu with text. This also happens at time when I click on an `NSUserNotification` shown by the app. I've googled a lot, but I couldn't find any reference to such an issue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the app
2. Again click on app icon from launchpad

This happens only once, after this the issue cannot be reproduced.

This is how the menu should look:

[image: Correct Menu]

Incorrect menu:

[image: Transparent NSMenu]

Here is my AppDelegate

```
import Cocoa
import Fabric
import Crashlytics

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        NSUserNotificationCenter.default.delegate = self
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NSApplicationCrashOnExceptions")
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

I've a controller for the Menu, which call some functions that render the actual menu

```
@IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(70))

override func awakeFromNib() {
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu

    updateTitle()
    setupMenu()
    renderMenu()
}
```

Comment: Your question is a black box unless you give code for the menu setup and rendering.
Is the issue that your background is transparent, text is gray or what?

Comment: @battlmonstr I've added more details, the menu renders fine 99% of the time. Rarely, when I click on the notification / app icon I get a weird outline of the menu.

Comment: Post the code of setupMenu/renderMenu especially how you render the background.

Comment: There is no code to render background, I just added several NSMenuItem using `statusMenu.addItem(item)`, The menu is rendering default dark theme background.

Comment: Can you try to hook to an event when the menu is about ot be shown, and force repaint? Like  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934483/force-nsview-to-redraw-programatically

Comment: Sure, I'll try that. I forgot to mention that I've a timer that re-renders the menu every seconds using -> `RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)`, could this cause the issue?

Comment: It could. Disable the timer, and see if the bug reproduces.

Comment: I'll try, but its very hard to reproduce this issue. It occurs like 1 in 100 times I open the menu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171422/discussion-between-arjun-komath-and-battlmonstr).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with one of my apps. The issue was that my app was not coming to the foreground when the menu activated. I solved it by implementing:

```
- (void) menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *) aMenu
{
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
```